# Iterating over list to find occurrences of element. Issue with code

Tags: c++, iterator, listiterator

Does anyone know what's wrong with this code?  I'm getting the following compilation error.  The goal is to find the occurrences of a string "p" and I took the idea from Stroustrup P57.  My assumption is that I could just increment the iterator to find additional occurrences, but that is not working.  Thanks

```
find.cc: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
find.cc:34:16: error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘LI {aka std::_List_const_iterator<Ent>}’ and ‘int’)
     i = find(i + 1, l.end(), e1);
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <list>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct Ent {
  string name;
  Ent(const string& name) : name(name) { }
  bool operator== (const Ent& right) const {
    return name == right.name;
  }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  list<Ent> l;

  for (char c = 'a'; c <= 'z'; c++) {
    Ent e(string(1, c));
    l.push_back(e);
  }

  Ent e1("p");

  typedef list<Ent>::const_iterator LI;

  LI i = find(l.begin(), l.end(), e1);

  int n = 0;
  while (i != l.end()) {
    ++n;
    i = find(i + 1, l.end(), e1);
  }

  cout << "find(" << e1.name << ") = " << n << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: In general, never use `std::list`. It's not python. Use `std::vector` by default. But in some cases `std::unique_ptr` or `std::deque` are more suitable.

Comment: `std::list` is fantastic in some circumstances. It has very forgiving [iterator invalidation rules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules), for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists iterators are bidirectional iterators but not randomaccess iterators. Hence they have no `operator+`, but only a `operator++`. You can write

```
++i;
i = find(i , l.end(), e1);
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks. find.cc:35:28: error: no matching function for call to ‘find(LI&, std::__cxx11::list<Ent>::iterator, Ent&)’
     i = find(i, l.end(), e1);

Comment: Change `typedef list<Ent>::const_iterator LI;` to `typedef list<Ent>::iterator LI;`.

Comment: Thanks!  That worked!  I'm assuming const_iterator worked before because a new const random access iterator was returned each time, vs incrementing the iterator in place.